# Hide custom checkbox from WooCommerce checkout based on a product ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I have code that adds a checkbox to the checkout page. If checked, adds additional fee to the order.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'checkout_shipping_form_packing_addition', 20);
    function checkout_shipping_form_packing_addition()
    {
        $domain = 'woocommerce';
    
        echo '<tr class="packing-select"><th>' . __('სამაჯური', $domain) . '</th><td>';
    
        $chosen   = WC()->session->get('chosen_packing');
    
        // Add a custom checkbox field
        woocommerce_form_field('chosen_packing', array(
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
            'class'     => array('form-row-wide packing'),
            'label'         => __('სამაჯურის ღირებულება 30₾', 'woocommerce'),
            'description'         => __('აღნიშნული სერვისით სარგებლობისთვის საჭიროა სამაჯურის შეძენა, თუ გსურთ შეძენა, მონიშნეთ ეს ველი, თუ უკვე გაქვთ სამაჯური ან ადგილზე გადაიხდით სამაჯურის ღირებულებას დატოვეთ მონიშვნის გარეშე'),
            'required'  => false,
        ), $chosen);
    
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
    
    // jQuery - Ajax script
    add_action('wp_footer', 'checkout_shipping_packing_script');
    function checkout_shipping_packing_script()
    {
        // Only checkout page
        if (is_checkout() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()) :
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($) {
                $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input#chosen_packing', function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                        data: {
                            'action': 'woo_get_ajax_data',
                            'packing': $(this).prop('checked') ? 1 : 0,
                        },
                        success: function(result) {
                            $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                            console.log('response: ' + result); // just for testing | TO BE REMOVED
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log(error); // just for testing | TO BE REMOVED
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
        else:
        WC()->session->__unset('chosen_packing');
        endif;
    }
    
    // Php Ajax (Receiving request and saving to WC session)
    add_action('wp_ajax_woo_get_ajax_data', 'woo_get_ajax_data');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_woo_get_ajax_data', 'woo_get_ajax_data');
    function woo_get_ajax_data()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['packing'])) {
            $packing = sanitize_key($_POST['packing']);
            WC()->session->set('chosen_packing', $packing);
            echo json_encode($packing);
        }
        die(); // Alway at the end (to avoid server error 500)
    }
    
    // Add a custom dynamic packaging fee
    add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_packaging_fee', 20, 1);
    function add_packaging_fee($cart)
    {
        if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
            return;
    
        if( WC()->session->get('chosen_packing') ){
            $label = __('სამაჯური', 'woocommerce');
            $cost = 30;
            $cart->add_fee($label, $cost);
        }
    }
```

I tried to use the following code to hide the checkbox when a specific product is in the cart. But it doesn't work. This feature works for other billing fields but does not hide this particular checkbox.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'disabling' );
 

     function disabling($fields){
        $product_id = array(15163); //product id which would trigger
        $in_cart = false;
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
           $product_in_cart = $cart_item['product_id'];
           if ( $product_in_cart === $product_id ) $in_cart = true; // checks if the product is in cart
        }
        if ( $in_cart ){
          unset($fields['billing']['chosen_packing']);
          unset($fields['shipping']['chosen_packing']);
      
          return $fields;
        }
        else {
          return $fields;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your first function with the following, to hide the checkbox if one of the specific product(s) is in cart:

```php
// Conditional function: Checks if one of the products is in cart
function is_in_cart( $products_ids ) {
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( in_array($item['product_id'], $products_ids) ) 
            return true; // Exit
    }
    return false; 
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'checkout_shipping_form_packing_addition', 20);
function checkout_shipping_form_packing_addition() {
    // Defined products that hide the checkout field
    if ( is_in_cart( array(15163) ) ) 
        return;

    echo '<tr class="packing-select"><th>' . __('სამაჯური', 'woocommerce') . '</th><td>';
    // Add a custom checkbox field
    woocommerce_form_field('chosen_packing', array(
        'type'        => 'checkbox',
        'class'       => array('form-row-wide packing'),
        'label'       => __('სამაჯურის ღირებულება 30₾', 'woocommerce'),
        'description' => __('აღნიშნული სერვისით სარგებლობისთვის საჭიროა სამაჯურის შეძენა, თუ გსურთ შეძენა, მონიშნეთ ეს ველი, თუ უკვე გაქვთ სამაჯური ან ადგილზე გადაიხდით სამაჯურის ღირებულებას დატოვეთ მონიშვნის გარეშე', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'    => false,
    ), WC()->session->get('chosen_packing') );

    echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

It should work.